# MySQL - Can using reserved words as table names decrease performance?

Tags: mysql, reserved-words

I know that doing something like this would be considered bad practice but if one were to create a table with fields like `from, to, desc` and did:

```
SELECT *
```

or

```
SELECT `from`, `to`, `desc`
```

With a massive data / result set would this have any kind of performance difference as opposed to using names like `sent_from, sent_to, description`?

Comment: Someone posted a link to the CakePHP docs, notably: "It should be noted that this decreases performance because each query needs to be traversed and manipulated before being executed". I think this is from within CakePHP itself that this problem comes about. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: If it is a question, then try to compare results of two queries like these - SELECT `from`, `to`, `desc` and SELECT c1, c2, c3... Just create similar tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there will be any or rather any significant difference in the performance if you are using reserved keywords as table name. The only thing which you will get and which you are already aware of, is the readability and the poor design of database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't think it decreases performance either but I am unsure and was hoping someone out there would say firmly that it does not! :)

Comment: @IndigoIdentity:- To confirm it firmly you have to create a test case and run it may be 1000 times and see the difference. I did the same with column names few years back and didnt found any difference(a marginal difference of few nanoseconds which I considered it because of the long names of the strings which I took). You can also do the similar and I bet you will not find any difference.

Comment: Well, I did give it a try. It's basically impossible for me to tell if there is any difference as there is always a marginal difference in the time it takes to run the query regardless. That being said, there is no noticeable difference between using and not using reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

Using keywords like 'from','to' would not bring down the performance, rather there would be instances of others confused while there is a need to update data.Some tools that has auto-complete features would consider it as a keyword rather than a field.It would be better to use the 'table_name.from' rather using 'from'.